# window.find(text) for Flash Portion

Tags: javascript

As per my knowledge I know that

```
window.find(text,true)
```

will work to search some text in design mode of web page. But it is failed if some portion of the page is programmed in Flash and the text I have specified is in that flash portion. Is there any alternative to search flash text as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can only search in flash files if you have created some sort of method to do so within your actionscript code and exported it for use.

Google has found a way to read some flash though for SEO use. Have a read of this article: http://www.searchengineworkshops.com/articles/flash.html